# What kind of UML relationship is accepting an enum in the constructor but not as an attribute of the object?

Tags: design-patterns, enums, uml

I'm designing a package where one particular class will accept several enums as arguments to the constructor. Those enums will not become attributes, but they will be used to instantiate objects that are. I don't have code yet, but here is a bit of psuedocode to illustrate my design idea:

```
Enum Type {

    TYPE_A(A::new), TYPE_B(B::new);

    private Supplier supplier;

    private Type(Supplier<X> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public X createInstance() {
        return supplier.get();
    }

}

Class SomeClass {

    Object someObject;

    public SomeClass(Type t) {
        someObject = t.createInstance();
    }
}
```

The above idea was inspired by the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924172/java-way-to-create-an-object-based-on-enum-type).

**How would I classify this relationship between `Type` and `SomeClass` above?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply this is a dependency from `SomeClass` towards `Type`.

See [Difference between association and dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230889/difference-between-association-and-dependency)